# Wrong Usage Of "In"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, usage, ellipsis

I have a question about the usage of the preposition "*in*" [here](http://news.yahoo.com/officers-floodlights-checkpoints-hunt-escapee-044251949.html#):

> Sweat was ***serving a sentence of life without parole in the killing of*** a sheriff's deputy in Broome County in 2002. Matt was serving 25 years to life for the killing and dismembering of his former boss.

The act of serving a sentence didn't happen as a part of the killing of a deputy.  So, the use of "*in*" alone seems off.  Would replacing "*in*" with "*in connection with*" be better?

Comment: The 'in' here I believe is a shortening of "in connection with" - ... of life without parole in connection with the killing of..."  So yes, with is better, but  it needed a little bit more.

Comment: I might replace _in_ with _for_.

Comment: If Sweat murdered the sheriff's deputy and had been prosecuted/sentenced then I would go for 'for' instead of 'in'.   Replacing with 'in connection with' would work in that situation and I would use it over using 'for' if it wasn't clear what his part was in the murder of the deputy or if he had yet to be judged.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually slightly more sensible than it sounds.

It could be taken to mean "...in the case of the killing of...". It takes the previous crime as being an entity in and of itself (which in both journalistic, academic, and legal terms, it is).